# Update multiple rows with different values in a single query - MySQL

Tags: mysql, rows

I'm new to MySQL.

**I'm using this to update multiple rows with different values, in a single query:**

```
UPDATE categories
    SET order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    title = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'New Title 2'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'New Title 3'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

I am using "WHERE" to improve performance (without it every row in the table would be tested).

**But what if I have this senario (when I don't want to update title for id 2 and 3):**

```
UPDATE categories
    SET order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    title = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

The above code will change the title for id 2 and 3 into "NULL"...

**What is the right way to make the query, but skip updating title for id 2 and 3 and still keep the performance  "WHERE id IN" gives ?**

Maybe like this

```
UPDATE categories
    SET order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    title = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        WHEN  THEN 
        WHEN  THEN 
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set title equal to itself when you don't want to update it to a different value.

```
UPDATE categories
    SET order = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 3
        WHEN 2 THEN 4
        WHEN 3 THEN 5
    END,
    title = CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        ELSE title
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name1` = CASE `id`
WHEN '1' THEN 'value_1'
WHEN '2' THEN 'value_2'
WHEN '3' THEN 'value_3'
ELSE `field_name1`
END,
`field_name2`= CASE id
WHEN '1' THEN 'value_1'
WHEN '2' THEN 'value_2'
WHEN '3' THEN 'value_3'
ELSE `field_name2`
END
```