# Update multiple Rows in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, sql-update

I have been looking around but I have not found an answer yet. Kindly help if you know the answer.

How do you update multiple rows in CI?

In my MySQL:

I have column names:

```
ID, Settings Name, Settings Value ( Settings Name is Unique )
```

I have the ff Data:

```
ID = 1, Settings Name = "Hello" , Settings Value = "True"
ID = 2, Settings Name = "World", Settings Value = "Good"
```

and more ...

I also have a form that gets the `Settings Value` but I am not sure how to update it on the DB. How to update the `True` for the `Hello` being the `Settings Name` and update the `Good` for the `World`.

I heard about `insert_batch()` but is there an `update_batch()`?

Comment: I think it might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759514/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-a-single-query-mysql

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Are you using Active record?

Yes there is an update batch: [$this->db->update_batch();](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

```
$data = array(
array(
  'ID' => 1 ,
  'Settings Name' => 'Hello' ,
  'Settings Value' => 'True'
),
array(
  'ID' => '2' ,
  'Settings Name' => 'World' ,
  'Settings Value' => 'Good'
)
);    

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'where_key');
```

From the documentation:

> The first parameter will contain the table name, the second is an associative array of values, the third parameter is the where key.

Comment: Thanks for this!!! I have been staring at that same documentation from CI but I just have the light bulb when you answer this Q. hehe foolish me.. Thanks again!

Comment: I have a follow up Qs: How to retrieve from the DB the posted values? is it the normal set_value() ? Thanks!

Comment: @JeffSimonsDecena, what do you mean retrieve from DB with normal set_value()? The set_value() in CI's documentation is used to repopulate a form. Retrieving data from the DB  can be found here [Selecting Data](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 8):

There is indeed an `update_batch()` [method available in CodeIgniter already](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update).

You can use it your example like so:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'ID' => 1,
        'Settings Name' => 'Hello',
        'Settings Value' => 'True'
    ),
    array(
        'ID' => 2,
        'Settings Name' => 'World',
        'Settings Value' => 'Good'
    )
);
$this->db->update_batch('tableName', $data, 'id');
```

So what you have is an array of arrays, the children basically hold the data for each row in the database. The first parameter for `update_batch()` is the name of the database table, the second is the `$data` variable and the third is the column you want to use in the `WHEN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple php code for perform this operations.

```
<?php
function basic_update($uwi='') {
$this->load->database();
$data = array(
'ID' => 1,
'Settings Name' => 'Hello',
'Settings Value' => 'True'  
);
$this->db->where('ID', '1');
$this->db->update('<table name>', $data);
$data1 = array(
    'ID' => 2,
    'Settings Name' => 'World',
    'Settings Value' => 'Good'
    );
    $this->db->where('ID', '2');
    $this->db->update('<table name>', $data1);
}
```

In $this->db->where('ID', '1'); ID is your table field and 1 is the value.
In array first parameter will contain the table name, the second parameter is an associative array of values

Comment: That's a bad way of doing multiple row updates, as you are running 2 or  more queries, where you can run only 1.