# How to update array of data in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am making a quiz backend process. Where backend user will needed to update questions and answers that has been posted or saved.

Right now I have a problem in the update process I cannot update the answers

An example of my UI

[See UI here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRAsb.png)

All data in answers textboxes has this element.

```
   <input type="text" name="choice[1]" class="form-control" value="Sydney" ?="">
```

My update in Controller

```
public function update()
{   

    $this->post_model->update_post();


    redirect('/');

}
```

My update in Model - $answer is null after I `var_dump` why?

```
public function update_post(){

    $answer = $this->input->post('choice');
    foreach($medicine as $key=>$val)
    {

        $data[] = array(
            'answer' => $answer[$key]
        );

        $this->db->where('id', $val);
        $updated = $this->db->update('answers');
    }

}
```

View

```
<?php echo form_open('posts/update'); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $posts['id']; ?>">
    Question:
    <input type="text" name="question" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $posts['question']; ?>" ?><hr>
    Answers:

    <?php foreach($questions as $question): ?>
        <input type="text" name="choice[<?php echo $question['id'] ?>]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $question['answer']; ?>" ?><hr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<hr>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save Changes">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update multiple Rows in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211967/update-multiple-rows-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @vadivela please dont suggest any irrelevant topics. no I dont update mulitple rows. I need to update data each or separated in columns

Comment: @vadivela - I have a problem in my query can you help me to fix it?