# How to update multiple rows with different values using Propel ORM?

Tags: orm, symfony-1.4, propel

If I have an array of primary keys, and then another key value pair of titles:

```
$article = array(
  array('Id' => 1, 'Title' => 'New Title'),
  array('Id' => 2, 'Title' => 'New Title2'),
  array('Id' => 3, 'Title' => 'New Title3'),
  array('Id' => 4, 'Title' => 'New Title4')
);
```

I am looking for a way to update my Article table in 1 Propel call.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. If you think about how to perform this kind of thing in MySQL, it wouldn't be in a single query. They would have to be separate statements e.g.

```
UPDATE `article` SET title = "New Title" WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE `article` SET title = "New Title2" WHERE id = 2;
```

You're probably already where that you can do bulk updates that match a specified criteria like this:

```
// set the select condition criteria
$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ArticlePeer::ID, 1);

// set the update criteria
$update = new Criteria();
$update->add(ArticlePeer::TITLE, 'New Title');

// we need the connection for update, so get default connection
$con = Propel::getConnection();

// finally, do the update
BasePeer::doUpdate($c, $update, $con);
```

But that's not going to help much in your instance because the select criteria condition changes in each update instance for you. Maybe you could enclose the above code in a for loop that loops through your array.

**Update:**

You could try a Propel hack like below (untested):

```
$article = array(
  array('Id' => 1, 'Title' => 'New Title'),
  array('Id' => 2, 'Title' => 'New Title2'),
  array('Id' => 3, 'Title' => 'New Title3'),
  array('Id' => 4, 'Title' => 'New Title4')
);

$ids = array();
$when = 'CASE id';
foreach ($article as $a) {
    $ids[] = $a['Id'];
    $when .= ' WHEN ' . $a['Id'] . ' THEN ' . $a['Title'];
}
$when .= ' END';

$c = new Criteria();
$c->add(ArticlePeer::ID, $ids, Criteria::IN);

$update = new Criteria();
$update->add(ArticlePeer::TITLE, $when);

$con = Propel::getConnection();

BasePeer::doUpdate($c, $update, $con);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Other ORMs are able to implement this type of SQL wrapper.  As for what the MYSQL query would look like it would utilize the CASE statement as such: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759514/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-a-single-query-mysql)

Comment: If you find a way to perform the MySql command in your link that would be great to know about. I've never seen those versions of Propel that are bundled with Symfony 1.* support these kind of commands though. I actually have found those earlier versions to be quite restrictive, especially with their support for joins etc.

Hope you find a way.